# IllegalBlockSizeException when using aes/ecb/pkcs5padding to decrypt a byte array

Tags: java, android, encryption, gradle, aes

I understand that aes encryption needs to be in blocks of 16, but I was under the impression that using `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");` padded the byte array to achieve this. My code is below:

**CipherUtils.java**

```
private static byte[] key = {
        0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79
};//"thisIsASecretKey";

public static byte[] EncryptByteArray(byte[] array)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

        return (cipher.doFinal(array));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}

public static byte[] DecryptByteArray(byte[] array)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(array);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}
```

**Main Program**

```
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);

        toDecrypt = new byte[fis.available()+1];

        int content;
        int i = 0;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {

            // convert to byte and display it
            toDecrypt[i] = (byte)content;
            i += 1;
        }

        byte[] decryptedStr = CipherUtils.DecryptByteArray(toDecrypt);

        FileOutputStream decryptedStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        decryptedStream.write (decryptedStr);
        decryptedStream.close();
```

The file at `path` was encrypted using the function in cipherutils.java and written to the file using `FileOutputStream.write`

Update- I'm building for Android using Gradle.

Comment: Start by unit-testing your methods with a hard-coded input: encrypting it and decrypting the result should lead to an output that is equal to the input. Once done, you'll realize that the encryption and decryption work fine, and that the problem is in the way you write and read your files. available() doesn't return the length of the file. And even if it did, you array contains an additional byte. So that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please don't use ECB mode. It's not semantically secure. You should use at least CBC mode with a random IV. At best, you should authenticate the ciphertexts. This is usually done either using an authenticated mode like GCM or running the ciphertext through HMAC (encrypt-then-MAC).

Comment: ... or running *the IV* and ciphertext though HMAC ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work something out using @JonSkeet's answer (thanks!) :

```
        File file = new File(path);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        toDecrypt = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fis.read(toDecrypt);

        byte[] decrypted = CipherUtils.DecryptByteArray(toDecrypt);
        FileOutputStream decryptedStream = new FileOutputStream(bookPath);
        decryptedStream.write (decrypted);
        decryptedStream.close();
```

As he pointed out, I shouldn't have been using the available() method. There was also a much better & faster way to write to the file than iterating through each byte! As per the comments, I have also changed the encryption to CBC mode with a random IV.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
toDecrypt = new byte[fis.available()+1];
```

Firstly, you're using the `available()` method, which is *never* a good idea. Next, even assuming it *is* returning the length of the file, you're adding 1 to it - why? You want just the bytes in the file, surely.

The simplest way to do that is just to use [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
byte[] toDecrypt = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
// TODO: Change the method name to follow Java conventions
byte[] decrypted = CipherUtils.DecryptByteArray(toDecrypt);
Files.write(Paths.get(path), decrypted);
```

Now you don't need to worry about closing the file streams, either... (If you'd managed to decrypt, you probably wouldn't be able to write, because you've still got the file open for reading in your current code.)

I'd also strongly recommend revisiting your exception "handling":

- Catching `Exception` is almost always a bad idea
- Calling `e.printStackTrace()` and then continuing as if nothing happened is almost always a bad idea

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm getting "error: package java.nio.file does not exist", but I'm on the latest version of Java. I'm using Gradle 2.4, and the Android Tools plugin version 1.2.0. Sorry, I'm really new to this and the majority of the code is not my own - my boss wants someone in-house to be able to work with Java!

Comment: @DomHarris: You're using Android? You never mentioned that anywhere in the question - that definitely affects what's available... *please* include crucial information like that when posting.